# Sum in base-12 javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate two numbers in javascript and the result should be
 in **base-12** but I don't know how it works. Can anyone tell me any example to help me, I was searching but didn't find anything

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use format options properly; quoting yourself makes you look like a medieval king.

Comment: What does "calculate two numbers" mean? Add them?